# Emberjs #each loop not working on array data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just trying to loop through some dummy data I generated just so I can style the site, I have this in my router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  chatMessages() {
      return [{
      username: "John Doe",
      message: "Blah Blah Blah",
      dispic: "http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"
    }]
  },
  activate() {
    this.controllerFor('chatroom').subscribe();
  }
});
```

and then in my `index.hbs`

```
    {{#each chatMessages as |chatMessage|}}
      {{chat-message username=chatMessage.username message=chatMessage.message dispic=chatMessage.dispic}}
    {{else}}
      {{chat-message username="System" message="There are currently no chat messages, feel free to start talking! Someone will join eventually" dispic="asd"}}
    {{/each}}
```

But I only ever see the else statement. Any information would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is setup incorrectly at the moment, you'll have to return your chatmessages in the model of your route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  chatMessages: [{
      username: "John Doe",
      message: "Blah Blah Blah",
      dispic: "http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"
  }],
  model(){
    return this.get('chatMessages')
  },
  activate() {
    this.controllerFor('chatroom').subscribe();
  }
});
```

And now you'll be able to access it in your template like this:

```
{{#each model as |chatMessage|}}
  {{chat-message username=chatMessage.username message=chatMessage.message dispic=chatMessage.dispic}}
{{else}}
  {{chat-message username="System" message="There are currently no chat messages, feel free to start talking! Someone will join eventually" dispic="asd"}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/320fee7ae5d302456072d41020b9e5b4?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C) that I set up for you. Then it's important to read [this section](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) of the guides again, as it explains the model hook in more detail in terms of the route, and [this part](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/controllers/) that explains how it is set on the controller.

Comment: Can you only use `#each` on models?

Comment: Ok so the model in a route is definitely confusing when you start. It's not related to the "model" where you define entities and their attributes, in the route's case, it's a "hook" that loads your data and sets it on the controllers model attribute.

Comment: See the answer, I updated the last part with a few links ?